# A decimal point format issue on de-serializing a JSON string in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I got an conversion error if clients passes {f: "1,00"} to servers for de-serialization with following .NET Object, the framework cannot recognize it as a valid **decimal** value. The clients are at '**id-id**' locale so "1,00" is actually "1.00" in decimal.

Can I tell the framework to use correct number formatter to workaround my issue?
Thanks.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class EntryParameter
{
    [DataMember(Name = "f")]
    public decimal Foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you somehow force your client not to pass , but only use . i think  , is not recognized as same as .

Comment: How do your clients create that string `{f: "1,00"}`? Since json serializers(JavaScriptSerializer,DataContractJsonSerializer,Json.Net) would create `{"f": 1.00}`

Comment: @L.B: we format the decimal 1.00 at server-side to string "1,00" so that our client can see the correct locale-compatible values.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this solution to make sure that decimal is recognized as specific format

```
value = "1,00";
   style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
   culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
   if (Decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   {
       decimal topaas=number;
   }
```

Comment: Hi COLD TOLD: How can I let built-in serialization mechanism make use your proposed solution?

Comment: Instead of  public decimal Foo { get; set; } use  public string  Foo { get; set; } and then it will be coming like this "1,00"; and then use above example to convert it to decimal